# wrapping svg:text with mbostock's wrap function

Tags: d3.js

Basically, I am trying to wrap the text in a svg:text element to some arbitrary width using the wrap() function from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) by Mike. My data is more nested than his and I attempted to adjust (er hack) it before passing it in, but without success. I have been staring at this for too long...and probably missing the obvious.

```
.text(function(d){
    var sel = d3.select(this); 
    sel[0][0].__data__ = d.name; 
    return wrap(sel,50);}
);
```

I put a minimal example in a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bA4G9/), with appropriate comments. The solution should not involve altering the present structure of the data since I cannot change it.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It may be better to use `foreignObject` and a `div` of fixed with for this.

Comment: Thanks Lars...foreignObject is not an option...no support in IE. Do you see any significant difference between the selection being passed in Mike's example and the one in mine?

Comment: Works for me if I use the same approach in the example -- http://jsfiddle.net/bA4G9/1/

Comment: Lars, a couple of points: calling the function like in the original was failing for me due to an ill-placed transition call that prevented the wrapping and thus threw me off. Once I got that working, I had to change Mike's function to consider the x attribute of the text being wrapped...0 will not cut it if the x,y of the text is calculated via some math for radial placement. I changed that. How do you want to do this? I could write my own answer with the improvement but your test is what triggered the solution. Would you rather post your answer and I will note the change via a comment?

Comment: Hang on, I'm not getting what you mean. Are you saying that the fiddle I modified does what you're looking for or does it not work in some way?

Comment: It does what I want but in my complete code (the fiddle was a waterdown version of it) I had placed a transition call that was preventing the wrap, so I thought it wasn't working. To summarize, before posting the question, I had tried the call like in the original but it did not work for me because of an ill-place transition. But I was only able to identify that after you posted your fiddle. Makes sense now?

Comment: Ah, I see. Not sure if I should post an answer though -- I've really just taken the code from the original example. As the transition was the problem, maybe you could post an answer explaining that?

Comment: Yes, that would be useful...I will do that and mention the change in the wrap function. And, as usual, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Per exchange with Lars in the comments above, an ill-placed transition seemed to prevent the wrapping of text, even though the wrap function is otherwise doing its job. Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bA4G9/2/) with a bunch of comments identifying the **location** of the problem although I am not yet clear on the **reason** behind the problem.

```
...
.transition().duration(1000) // transition here "prevents" wrapping
.text(function(d) { return d.name; })
.call(wrap, 40)
...
```

One note of interest pertains to the wrap function itself. It uses the y coord from the text being wrapped but assumes an x coord of 0. This did not work for me because my text is placed via some math calculations. Leaving aside the fact that I should move said calculation up to the parent g, it is a situation that can happen. The solution is simple...use the x coord from the element being wrapped, just as it is done with the y coord:

```
y = text.attr("y"),
x = text.attr("x"), // added x attribute of text being wrapped
```

And then make sure to use it in the rest of the function:

```
...
tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
...
tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
...
```